# Themes overriding each other?

Tags: android, styles

In my styles.xml file I have a style to remove the title bar and other styles to change my tabwidget's font size:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<style name="RemoveTitleBar" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

</style>

<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/CustomTabWidget</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTabWidget" parent="android:style/Widget.TabWidget">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomTabWidgetText</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTabWidgetText" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

In my AndroidManifest.xml file I set the RemoveTitleBar style to the application which works fine:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_test_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/RemoveTitleBar"
....
```

However when I apply the CustomTheme style to my activity with tabs, I get the title bar back. But if I remove the line it works fine.

```
<activity   android:name=".TabActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"> </activity>
```

Am I going about this the wrong way or do I have to change something in my styles.xml file? Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are extending `CustomTheme` with `"android:style/Theme"`:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/CustomTabWidget</item>
</style>
```

and the `titleBar` is available in in this you aren't removing the `titleBar`, you will again need to remove the `titleBar` like this:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/CustomTabWidget</item>
    <item name="android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. I actually changed both styles parent to be parent="android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" so I didn't need to place it under each item. Thanks a lot!   :o)